# UITableView Separator line

Tags: iphone, uitableview

How can I change the separator line that appears at the end of each cell in UITableView?
I want to have an image that is a thin separator type line image.

Answer (score 95):

Set the `separatorStyle` of the tableview to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone`. Add your separator image as subview to each cell and set the frame properly.

Comment: will you plz give me an example.

Comment: [separatorImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, separatorImageView.image.size.height)];

Comment: [cell.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)]; wasnt able to do so :(

Comment: And what about the ones the normal UITableView draws when the cells don't fill the screen?

Comment: It's sad that this answer is still the best due to separator line bugs.

Answer (score 65):

Try this

**Objective C**

```
  [TableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];

  [TableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Divider_line@2x.png"]]];
```

**Swift**

```
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine
    tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "YOUR_IMAGE_NAME")!)
```

Comment: Awesome answer Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @ Sakshi - I set the separator color instead of an image and it looks great too. `table.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine
        table.separatorColor = UIColor(red: 245/255, green: 245/255, blue: 245/255, alpha: 1.0)`

Answer (score 30):

First you can write the code:

```
{    [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];}
```

after that

```
{    #define cellHeight 80 // You can change according to your req.<br>
     #define cellWidth 320 // You can change according to your req.<br>

    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
    {
         UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"seprater_line.png"]];
        imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, cellHeight, cellWidth, 1);
        [customCell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
         return  customCell;

     }
}
```

Comment: The problem with solutions like this that just add a subview to the cell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is that they will add a new one every single time the cell gets reused, never removing the old ones. It should only be added once, so you would do it in a `UITableViewCell` subclass.

Answer (score 7):

Set the color of the separator to be patterned with your image.

in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mySeparatorImage"]];
```

Answer (score 5):

My project is based on iOS 7
This helps me

`[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];`

Then put a subview into cell as separator!

Comment: That does not answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a UIImageView that is, for example, 1 point high and as wide as the cell's frame, and then set its origin to the bottom left corner of the cell.

Comment: Don't forget to turn off the default separator style for the table view: `[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];`

Comment: can u give me rough code so i can start, how can i set its origin to cell's bottom left corner ?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
UIImageView *separator = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"separator.png"]];
[cell.contentView addSubview: separator];
```

That's an example of how I got it to work pretty well.

Remember to set the separator style for the table view to none.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the way to do this via storyboard in XCode 10.2.1. Separator defaults to `default` which is the line. Set it to `none` to remove the line.

[image: tableview_separator]

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely help. Working. 
but set separator "none" from attribute inspector.
Write following code in  **cellForRowAtIndexPath**  method

```
 UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,           
 cell.contentView.frame.size.height - 1.0,      
 cell.contentView.frame.size.width, 1)];

    lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lineView];
```

Comment: I tried this even with `[cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:lineView];` and it mostly doesn't show except the far right and left sides.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3/4**

Custom separator line, put this code in a custom cell that's a subclass of UITableViewCell(or in CellForRow or WillDisplay TableViewDelegates for non custom cell):

```
let separatorLine = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 8, y: 64, width: cell.frame.width - 16, height: 2))
separatorLine.backgroundColor = .blue
addSubview(separatorLine)
```

in viewDidLoad method:

```
tableView.separatorStyle = .none
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options to change the separator style of a uitableview if you want to change the default options which are no separators, solid line or etched line.

1. The easiest consist in including a separator line background image
   to each cell view. You may check then where is located your cell in
   the tableview to apply the right background image that will give you
   either a separator line on top of the cell or at the bottom of the
   cell.

   Set the separator style to none in the viewDidLoad of your
   tableview:

   > [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

   Set your background image in the (UITableViewCell
   *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath function

   > ```
   >  UIImage* yourBgImg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgImage.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5)];
   > ```
   >
   > cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:yourBgImg];

   check the position of your cell in the section with the following:

   > NSInteger sectionRows = [tableView
   >   numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPathsection]];     NSInteger row =
   >   [indexPath row];
2. Add the separator line as a cell. I find a post recently for this
   here:
   http://www.dimzzy.com/blog/2012/01/separator-cells-for-uitableview/#disqus_thread

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate way to add a custom separator line to a `UITableView` by making a `CALayer` for the image and using that as the separator line.

// make a CALayer for the image for the separator line

```
CALayer *separator = [CALayer layer];
separator.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"].CGImage;
separator.frame = CGRectMake(0, 54, self.view.frame.size.width, 2);
[cell.layer addSublayer:separator];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try below:

```
UIView *separator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.contentView.frame.size.height - 1.0, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, 1)];
separator.backgroundColor = myColor;
[cell.contentView addSubview:separator];
```

or

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"separator.png"]];
   imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 1);
   [customCell.contentView addSubview:imageView];

   return customCell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to add a separator line under each tableview cell can be done in the storyboard itself.
First select the tableview, then in the attribute inspector select the separator line property to be single line. After this, select the separator inset to be custom and update the left inset to be 0 from the left.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNPOO.png)