# Separated cells in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, distance, cells

I want `UITableView` to show cells in section separated (have distance, blank space, between them).

So I've come up with this:

InventoryViewController.m

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[[InventoryStore sharedInventory] allInventories] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Inventory *p = [[[InventoryStore sharedInventory] allInventories]
                  objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];

    StepperCell *cell = [tableView
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"StepperCell"];

    [cell setController:self];
    [cell setTableView:tableView];

    [[cell nameLabel] setText:[p inventoryName]];
    [[cell valueLabel] setText:
     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%d", [p value]]];
    [[cell quantityLabel] setText:
     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [p quantity]]];
    cell.stepper.value = [p quantity];

    return cell;
}
```

and of course in AppDelegate.m

```
InventoryViewController *inventoryViewController = [[InventoryViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

My question is, is there a better or simpler way to separate cells, but in the same section?
I want to have one section, and draw data from one array, but these cells should have distance between each other.

Comment: You could try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804632/uitableview-separator-line  or    this:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521310/how-to-increase-the-uitableview-seperator-height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the table has blank separators (i.e. separatorStyle set to UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone) then you can inject blank cells between each cell.

e.g.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 if (indexPath.row % 2) {
 /* Your cell rendering code goes here */
 }
 else {
  UITableViewCell * blankCell = ....;
 }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return (numberOfInventoryItems * 2) - 1;
}
```