# Remove spacing between UITableViewCells

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have UITableViewCells in the same section which have gaps between them. I coloured each cell's contentView background and did an NSLog to show that it's the same height as the cells.

Still, there's a gap between them. They're definitely in the same section as each other. Any ideas as to what could be causing the gap?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4804690/792677

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have used this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 78;
}
```

And Checked that the Cell really is 78(just for arguments sake) in IB.
And then use:

```
tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 0.0;
```

And set the style of the tableView:

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

And the last solution I've bumped into over the years is that sometimes you need to extend your background image with a pixel for some reason. I don't think this is a good solution at all, cause it doesn't really address the real problem, but rather puts a crappy bandaid on it.

```
cellFrameBackground.size.height += 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting seperator style to none?

```
tableview.separatorType = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a 1 pixel gap, that is the cell separator.  You can remove this by setting a property on the table view:

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

If you wanted to change the color of that separator use the `separatorColor` property.

---

If you are talking about a gap bigger than 1 pixel, can you post a screenshot and your cell code?

Answer (score 0):

To add to the set of great answers, sometimes you just need to extend the background height as mentioned by Leeloo:

```
cellFrameBackground.size.height += 1;
```

Then, make your cell clip to bounds:

```
cell.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

And, voila.