# How to set an image for Cell Separator in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my table view, I need to set the cell separator as an image that I have with me. How can I do this?

Comment: Simply put it on bottom of your custom cell. and apply default cell separation style to none.

Comment: You can achieve like [this][1] link. This is duplication question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804632/uitableview-separator-line

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple solution is you can set a pattern image as cell seperator.

```
[tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:...]]];
```

Or you can simply add a UIImageView in the cell content view

```
UIImageView *imagView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"seprater.png"]];
imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0,cell.contentView.frame.size.height - 1.0, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, 1);
[customCell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: The first code solved my problem. But my cell separator seems to be aligned to the right side. Is there any way I can solve this?

Comment: @HarikrishnanT it is the issue for ios 7. you should use this for iOS7 - `if ([tblvw respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)])
[tblvw setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];`

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably to set the table's separatorStyle to UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone.

And manually adding/drawing a line (perhaps in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:) when you want it.

In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

...

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    // Drawing our own separatorLine here because I need to turn it off for the
    // last row. I can only do that on the tableView and on on specific cells.
    // The y position below has to be 1 less than the cell height to keep it from
    // disappearing when the tableView is scrolled.
    UIImageView *separatorLine = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, cell.frame.size.height - 1.0f, cell.frame.size.width, 1.0f)];
    separatorLine.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"grayDot"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:1 topCapHeight:0];
    separatorLine.tag = 4;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLine];

    [separatorLine release];
}
```

// Setup default cell settings.

```
...
UIImageView *separatorLine = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:4];
separatorLine.hidden = NO;
...
// In the cell I want to hide the line, I just hide it.
seperatorLine.hidden = YES;
```

...
In viewDidLoad:

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

to active this put an image view at the bottom of your cell and assign an image to it .also please make sure you have set cellSeperatorStyle as None

That should work

Answer (score 0):

```
{    [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];}

    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
    {
         UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"<image name>"]];
        imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, cellHeight, cellWidth, 1);
        [customCell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
         return  customCell;

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to make SeparatorStyle to none by following code

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

after that add image too the end of every cell

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{
     ..... 

     UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"seprater.png"]];
     [imgView sizeToFit];
     [Cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];

     .....

 }
```