# UITableView: customize separator

Tags: swift, uitableview

My question is very simple, how to implement a separator like this in UITableView.

[image]

I used to try adding CAShapeLayer that contained a dashed line to Cell.layer by this code

```
let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
let path = UIBezierPath(); path.lineWidth = 0.2
path.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(10, cell.height))
path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(screenWidth - 20, cell.height))
let shapeLayer:CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.3).CGColor
shapeLayer.fillColor = nil
shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [1,3]
shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath
cell.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

But it didn't work with  self-sizing table view cell

> tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableView Separator line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804632/uitableview-separator-line)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with an `image` which has your dotted line. Try this:

```
self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "YourDottedImage")!)
```

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow, how about create a subclass of tUITableViewCellSeparatorStyle and do something and do something fun inside :))

Comment: Are you sure you can subclass `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle`?

Comment: To be honestly, I think it's imposible :)), but we are able to extend ex by extension or in another way

Answer (score 0):

You could try to move line upward

```
path.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(10, cell.height-1))
path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(screenWidth - 20, cell.height-1))
```